# Convert latitude / longitude to X/Y

Tags: java, android, latitude-longitude, geography

I'm working on a geo-localisation project. I have an image of my campus , I found the 4 Long/Lat of the 4 corners but now I'm stuck to find a way to convert this to a pixel localisation.
I found a lot of topics about this but it's not very clear to me.

Comment: You question is quite unclear: are you trying to produce a function that takes lat/long as input, and outputs the x/y pixel location within your image? Your question also seems not specific to Java.

Comment: Yes it's what I want

Comment: What you are trying to do is called "[Map Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection)." For large-scale maps, it is a problem that is both broad and deep. But, for _informally_ mapping an area as small as a college campus, you can fake it: https://wuciawe.github.io/transform/2014/09/30/simple-convertion-from-longitude,-latitude-to-x,-y-in-small-area.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the method that can be used to get distance (in meters) between two LatLon coordinates. Once you have that it's then just some simple math to map it into pixels of your image.

```
public static double distance(LatLon loc1, LatLon loc2) {
    double EARTH_RADIUS = 6371000; // in meters

    double lat1 = Math.toRadians(loc1.latitude);
    double lon1 = Math.toRadians(loc1.longitude);
    double lat2 = Math.toRadians(loc2.latitude);
    double lon2 = Math.toRadians(loc2.longitude);

    // based on https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

    double a = Math.sin((lat2 - lat1) / 2.0);
    double b = Math.sin((lon2 - lon1) / 2.0);
    double c = a * a + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * b * b;
    double distanceRadians = 2.0 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(c));

    return EARTH_RADIUS * distanceRadians;
}
```

latitude is from range [-90,90] and longitude is from range [-180,180]

Comment: This is taking lat long input in degrees, right?

Comment: That's correct. latitude being from range [-90,90] and longitude being from range [-180,180]

Comment: It work like a charm but it give me a distance from the center that represent a circle. How do I know the angle to compute the x,y?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate? You have latlon coordinates of all corners, with above function you can calculate distance between them in metric system, your image is probably aligned across meridians and parallels, which means all the values can be directly mapped to each other. You have all data for any calculations that you may need.